# What is the average distance between two random points inside a circle?

Tags: circles, random

Assume you have a circle with some radius r. What is the average distance between two random points inside the circle?

(Edit: This is different from [this already answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695020/expected-value-of-the-distance-between-2-uniformly-distributed-points-on-circle), because here the points are inside the circle area, not on the circle circumference.)

Comment: Do you mean the circle interior, or the circumference?

Comment: I mean the interior

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question because that appears to be about points *on the circle* whereas this is about points *in* the circle.

Comment: For this problem it really matters how you are choosing the points.  If you are choosing them with uniform distribution relative to a cartesian plane, or if you are choosing them with uniform radius and uniform angle.  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Average distance between two points in a circular disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/average-distance-between-two-points-in-a-circular-disk)

Comment: @TobyMak It is definitely the same question, but the solution is a link to a broken link to a missing external pdf, so not really a solution.  I think that kind link-only answer is discouraged, not sure how it affects dups though.

Comment: Well, there is another solution below the one you mentioned where the proof does not rely on any external links. I don't think the answers are lacking in any way, such that they are incomplete without using external links, so closing this question as a duplicate is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch. Let $S$ be the distance between the points, and let $X$ be the distance of the first point from the center of the circle.

Then compute:

- $F_{S|X}(s|x)=P(S \ge s | x)$
- $F_S(s)=P(S \ge s ) = \int F_{S|X}(s|x) \, f_X(x) \, dx$
- $E(S) = \int_0^\infty (1-F_S(s)) ds$

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a good approach