# expected distance between two points on the circle

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

We choose two arbitrary points on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ independently. Treated those points as from a circle with radius equal to $1$, find the expected distance between them (along the chord).

I completely don't know how to start it.

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695020/expected-value-of-the-distance-between-2-uniformly-distributed-points-on-circle).

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$A=(\cos (a),\sin (a)) $$and
$$B =(\cos (b),\sin (b)), $$ then

$$d (A,B)^2=1+1-2 \cos (a-b) $$
$$=2 (1-\cos (a-b))=4\sin^2 (\frac {a-b}{2}). $$

thus, the distance between $A $ and $B $ is
$$2|\sin (\frac {a-b}{2})|$$

Comment: I would assume the expected answer should be $4/\pi $.

Comment: @user355705 It must depend on the points.

Comment: The expectation value in the sense of probability theory?