# A simple problem on regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ be the vertice of an regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle, $P$ is a point on the circle.

What is the maximum and the minimum values of $\sum_{k=1}^n|PA_k|$?

My idea : Maybe we can define $\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}$, $A_k=\omega^k$ and $P=e^{i\theta}$, then

$$\sum_{k=1}^n|PA_k|=\sum_{k=1}^n|e^{i\theta}-e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}|=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{i(-\arg (P-A_k))}(P-A_k)=...$$

In this way, perhaps we can write the final result in the form of trigonometric functions, so that it is convenient to find its maximum and minimum values. But I failed to expand and simplify it, can anyone help me?

Comment: Because the distance function is symmetric it is enough to consider the case when $P$ moves between $A_1$ and $A_2$. Further on this arch the function is again symmetric with respect to "the middle point", say $A_{1,2}$. So, max and min can be achieved at $A_1,A_2$ (which are the same) or at the middle point. Now one has to compute these values and decide which one is bigger.

Comment: @Sacio How to prove that it can take an extreme value on the midpoint? It's not an obvious fact, because we don't know anything about the properties of this function.

Comment: Right, it is symmetric with respect to the middle point, one has to show that it is monotonic on the part which may not be obvious ... .

Answer (score 3):

Using simple trigonometry, we have

$$S(\theta)=\sum_{k=1}^n|PA_k|=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin{\frac{\theta+\frac{2k\pi}{n}}{2}}, \text{where } 0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{n}.$$

Then

$$\frac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}\theta}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos{\frac{\theta+\frac{2k\pi}{n}}{2}}$$

Based on symmetry in the unit circle,

$$\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{n}\implies \frac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}\theta}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos{\left((1+2k)\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}=0$$

As $\theta$ decreases from $\dfrac{\pi}{n}$ to $0$, every term in the series $\dfrac{\text{d}S}{\text{d}\theta}$ increases. From this it follows that $S_\text{min}=S(0)$ and $S_\text{max}=S\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right).$

We know that the [mean distance between two points on the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695020/expected-value-of-the-distance-between-2-uniformly-distributed-points-on-circle) is $\dfrac{4}{\pi}$. From this it follows that as $n\to\infty$, both $S_\text{min}$ and $S_\text{max}$ approach $\dfrac{4n}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

[image]

If centered at origin, the vector sum of all polar symmetric vectors or forces $AP$ ( inclined at same $\pi/k$ to each next/consecutive vector) vanishes. So,

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n|OA_k|+\sum_{k=1}^n| A_k P|== n|OA| +0 $$

where $\vec {OA}$ is the constant eccentric vector. Since polygon vectors sum up to zero (no matter radius length), the summation to $A$ or $P$ is same. The former constant eccentric vector is summed $n$ times.

Comment: In the last expression, $k.|OP|$, what does $k$ mean? $k$ is the index of summation in the previously written series; $k$ has no meaning without the series.

Comment: Thanks, that should be $n$, number of vertices of the polygon.

Comment: Then $\sum_{k=1}^n|PA_k|=n|OP|=n$, which is independent of the location of $P$. But $\sum_{k=1}^n|PA_k|$ depends on the location of $P$ (this is easy to see when $n=2$).

Comment: Please see graphic edit.